# Jenkins REST API is better to use the XML or the Python API?

Tags: python, xml, rest, api, jenkins

I am trying to get some setting out of a job in Jenkins, example:

```
hudson.tasks.Shell
```

that's the part of what script to run, I do get it on the:

```
my_job/api/xml
```

but when I use the Python REST API directory I don't see even if I do:

```
 /api/python?depth=100
```

should be better if I work with all my functions using the XML, or is better to use the Python? Not sure if one does provide more info than the other one.

Comment: Why not just call the *JSON* API?

Comment: i think json have the same info as the python,  just python you can do the eval()  and get the directory directly with out having to deal reading a json, (plus i think python or json itself have issues with singles and /or double quotes )

Comment: But if you're using e.g. `requests` you just call `response.json()`, writing code that uses eval is a bad sign. If you're not getting all the data you want, have you tried using the `tree` query parameter?